# unable to find valid certification path to requested target Android Studio. One project works has no certificate errors, other doesn't

Tags: android-studio, client-certificates

I am getting the dreaded Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target in one of my cloned projects.

One of my projects builds just fine, the other doesn't.  I've tried reinstalling the certificate, I have "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically" checked in Tools -> Server Certificates.

Any ideas?  I am on Hedgehog.